# How to create an inline div that shrinks with its parent

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a layout with two elements on the same row. I'm facing these requirements

- Elements must remain on same row, never wrap to second line
- Length of elements depends on data and user input (static after loading the page but not known in advance)
- The available width may change when the window is resized

This is as far as I got with `inline-block` elements:

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">Button</div>
  <div class="button">Rather long button text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

This essentially cuts off the second element. Ideally, it would have a reduced size and look like this as if it had a `max-width`

[image]

But the width may change. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: It would be of great help if you could make some jsfiddle or jshint or codesendbox with your problem...

Comment: try to use text-overflow

Comment: @LazarNikolic I assumed that a Stack Overflow code snippet would be just as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element needs to have fixed dimensions for text-ellipsis or overflow to work, thats the reason why your max-width works. If your element doesn't have a fixed width or fixed max-width, it can take as much space it wants and it won't show ellipsis.

You can use `float` to achieve this. Any block element followed by a floated element will take the remaining width as the full width.

So, if you float your first button, second button will automatically take the remaining width as full width (fixed width).

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.button:first-child {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">Button</div>
  <div class="button">Rather long button text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, that's a great trick! Thank you very much for the solution and explaining the details.

Comment: This solution meets the requirements I guess. But if the data will be dynamic and change on the go, this solution will break. Just FYI

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are not clear to me, but what I understood so far, here is the solution,If you need something else, please let me know.

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">Button Button Button Button Button</div>
  <div class="button">Rather long button text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet button text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet butto button text lorem ipsum dolor sit ametn text lt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try and play with it, by  increasing and decreasing text for both the elements

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    // if you want to break into new line if case the buttons exceed available width of 
    //parent if want to remain in same line them set it to no-wrap
}
```